# Why do I get an access violation when I create a form within a class if the class instance is not a variable defined in the calling procedure

Tags: forms, class, delphi, access-violation

I am trying to use a class to display a progress indicator.

If I declare ProgressIndicator as a variable within the calling procedure, everything works fine, and ANewForm displays as I would expect.

However, the following code produces an access violation.  Can anyone help me to understand why?

```
unit Main;

interface

*uses
  Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Forms,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Progress;
type
  TProgressIndicator = class
  private
  public
    ANewForm : TForm;
    constructor Create;
  end;
type
  TfmMain = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    ProgressIndicator : TProgressIndicator;
  end;
var
  fmMain: TfmMain;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
constructor TProgressIndicator.Create;
  begin
     ANewForm := TForm.Create(Application);
     ANewForm.Show;
  end;
procedure TfmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ProgressIndicator.Create;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: ProgressIndicator is a local variable. As soon as TForm1.CreateProgressIndicator return, that variable is invalidated beause it is located on the stack. Prograes indication should be declared in one of the public/protected/private section of TForm1 so that it remains accessible after CreateProgressIndicator returns.

Comment: I have just tried that.  I still get the access violation.

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: You tried? It should work. So maybe you made another error. Please show the COMPLETE code you have done. Without that information you won't get a good answer and your question risk to be closed.

Comment: you did not create an instance of ProgressIndicator. The correct syntax would be AProgressIndicator := TProgressIndicator.Create;

Comment: Thank you!  But I am still puzzled why it worked if I declared ProgressIndicator as a variable inside the calling procedure.  Can you explain that to me?

Comment: `ProgressIndicator` is nothing but a variable. You cannot create an instance of a variable; you have to create an instance of a **class**. The class is `TProgressIndicator`, and it's `Create` method returns an instance of the class, which is stored in `ProgressIndicator`, which you can now use to refer to the instance of the class. Think of a house - `TProgressIndicator` is the blueprint, and once you build it, it's a `ProgressIndicator` where you could actually live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between `ProgressIndicator.Create` and `TProgressIndicator.Create`. Usually, you want to use the second form which says, "create a new instance of class `TProgressIndicator`". The first form says, "take an instance of `TProgressIndicator` which is stored in the variable `ProgressIndicator` and call its `Create` method". The problem is, it **doesn't** create that instance. In your case, `ProgressIndicator` is `nil`, because all class members are initialized to a zero-like value at the construction time, which is not a problem per-se - it still is linked to the class data so it can actually call the `Create` method. The method tries to create the form, which succeeds, and then tries to store it to the `ANewForm` field, because the in-memory address of `ANewForm` is `Self` + offset; for your code, the offset is probably 0, `Self` is nil, which gives a final address of `(nil + 0) = 0` and the memory location 0 is located in a memory page which is prohibited from all access. That's why you get an Access Violation.

What you want is:

```
procedure TfmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ProgressIndicator := TProgressIndicator.Create;
  end;
```

That will first create a new instance and then work with that.

Comment: Thank you!  I have not really thought about what is going on "under the bonnet" before.  But going back to my original question - why does it work if I use a local variable,  but not a form variable?  From your answer, am i to deduce that for a local variable, the memory location would be something other than 0?

Comment: Local variables are "random". It's quite possible that it contains an address that is actually valid.